# Horizontal scrollbar for fenced code blocks in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, kramdown, rouge

How can I enable horizontal scrollbar for my fenced code blocks in jekyll using kramdown and rouge?

Is there any parameter I could add to my `_config.yml` file maybe? Essentially I want to mimic the code blocks from GitHub as shown below

[image: horizontal scrollbar]

But this is what I end up having instead

[image: no scrollbar]

Any ideas?

Comment: You should show us how this code is written in your `.md` file, really, because the issue could well be there.

Comment: The code in the markdown file is formatted exactly the same as the GitHub markdown files are I.e I use  three quotes ``` language followed by code and I end this also with``` I will post my markdown file if need in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brad West said this wasn't a kramdown issue after all. I just had to do the following modifications to my base CSS file

```
pre {
  overflow: auto; /* I added this */
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
 /* white-space: pre-wrap; I deleted this
  word-wrap: break-word;  and this
  word-break: break-all; and also this */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS `overflow` issue, not a Jekyll issue.

Add the following to your `pre` element:

```css
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: You are right I also had to delete some other css parameters as well. I will post my complete answer soon.